# clEnqueTask showing deprecated in openCL 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, opencl

I am trying to build a hello world program in Visual Studio using OpenCL AMD SDK, but it is saying that a few commands are deprecated. I tried to define a macro `CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS`, but it's still not working. What do I need to do?

For the code I referred to : https://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/first-opencl-program/

[image: ImageLink]

Comment: They deprecated it for a reason; it's very terribly useful. They are encouraging you to do something else.

Comment: They deprecated clEnqueueTask() because launching a single thread without parallelism in CL is completely pointless. Leaving it there just makes people that don't know anything about CL use it in a for loop and leading to horrible performance. Use the standard clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoink! Stealing DarkZeros comment.

From https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueTask.html we read:

> clEnqueueTask is equivalent to calling clEnqueueNDRangeKernel with
>   work_dim = 1, global_work_offset = NULL, global_work_size[0] set to 1,
>   and local_work_size[0] set to 1.

Replace your clEnqueueTask with clEnqueueNDRangeKernel as described above.